# File extension types compiling apps

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm taking the android nano degree program and submitted my project with a couple files marked .old so I could reference them later.  This may have been unprofessional and probably not appropriate for a submission, but the reviewer said the app couldn't compile because of them...

I am running the whole course off of my phone via AIDE for compiling and it compiles and runs just fine... Does anyone know if it would cause a compile error in android studio or eclipse?

I don't own a computer to check this very simple thing.

Comment: Which extension did those files have before.

Comment: You said marked .old. But how? Did you add it to the file name or did you change extension?

Comment: Utility.java.old,  was not referenced by anything in any other files

Comment: What do you mean with what you just said?

Comment: In Eclipse i rename files to Utility.javaX without problems. They are excluded then.